# Usar un solo broadcast para manejar los eventos de wifidirecto

Tags: backgroundworker, wifi

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicacion que comparta datos por medio de wifidirecto. Mi app lanzara un worker para recibir datos, se que para la conexion wifip2p es necesario tener un beroadcast que registre los eventos de la conexion. Para multiples dispositvos conectados quiero usar un solo broadcastreceiver para economizar la memoria del dispositivo. El mecanismo funciona de la siguiente manera: Cuando se conecta algun dispositivo wifidirecto se dispara un broadcast receiver y este a su vez lanza el worker de recepcion de datos y a su vez este worker necesita un broadcastreceiver para monitoriar los eventos wifidirecto; solo que para multiples conexiones se dispararan varios broadcastreceivers de estos ultimos mencionados. ¿Cada worker tiene que registrar su propio broadcastreceiver que maneje los eventos de la conexion? En la siguiente app demo¿Cuantos broadcast se ponen en ejecucion?[sample app wifidirecto](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/)

Lo que estoy pensando es que quisiera un solo broadcast para todos los workers que se puedan lanzar simultaneamente. Pero me es imposible obtener la referencia al broadcastreceiver(que deberia ser unico) en cada worker.

Necesito una aclaracion sobre estos componentes

```
public class CastReceiverIniciarServicio extends BroadcastReceiver {


private WorkManager mWorkManager;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    
    mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {


        Toast toast =
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "trabajo wifi de fondo iniciado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();


        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        //WifiP2pInfo netInfo= (WifiP2pInfo) networkInfo;


        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {                
            
                // Passing params
                Data.Builder data = new Data.Builder();
                //data.put("network_info",networkInfo);

                mWorkManager.enqueueUniqueWork("WorkerServerReceptor", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerServerReceptor.class)
                        .setInputData(data.build())
                        .build());
            }

        }

    } 
    
}
```

Este el worker:

```
public class WorkerServerReceptor extends Worker {

   public WorkerServerReceptor(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Result doWork() {
    //quiero obtener la referencia al broadcast que quiero que sea unico(el broadcast del codigo de abajo)
    //Si no se esta ejecutando el broadcast de abajo ejecutarlo

    //codigo de envio......

    return Result.success();
}
```

}

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private WifiP2pManager manager;
private Channel channel;
private WiFiDirectActivity activity;

/**
 * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
 * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
 * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
 */
public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
        WiFiDirectActivity activity) {
    super();
    this.manager = manager;
    this.channel = channel;
    this.activity = activity;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
 * android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
        } else {
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
            activity.resetData();

        }
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
        // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
        // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));
        }
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P peers changed");
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            // we are connected with the other device, request connection
            // info to find group owner IP

            DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) activity
                    .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
            manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, fragment);
        } else {
            // It's a disconnect
            activity.resetData();
        }
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));

    }
}
```

}